# Avoid counter increment in Python loop

Tags: python

How can I avoid having to increment the `sequence` counter manually in the following Python code:

```
sequence = 0
for value in random.sample(range(1000), 7):
  # do something with value and sequence
  sequence += 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enumerate! You can refer to the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
for sequence, value in enumerate(random.sample(range(1000), 7)):
    # do something with value and sequence
```